# Change in template depending on whether a child route is active

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking for a way for templates to change depending on whether a child route is active or not.

Let's say we have the routes `/post/1/` and `/post/1/comments`.

I'd like `post.hbs` to be able to do something like this:

```
<div class={{if isChildRouteActive 'compact' 'expanded'}}>...</div>
{{outlet}}
```

Such that `/post/1` would yield `isChildRouteActive=false` and `/posts/1/comments` would yield `isChildRouteActive=true`.

One could conceptualize it this way:

```
{{#if outlet}}...{{else}}...{{/if}}
```

How can I expose this property to all of my templates?

Answer (score 0):

I think `index` child route will be good for you. Every parent route has `index` route child, to show something when others children routes are inactive. See `index route` in nested routes section here:  http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/defining-your-routes/

In your example:

```
// post template
{{outlet}}

//post/index template
You see this text when post.comments route is inactive. If you activate post.comments this text will dissapear and you will see comments quantity.

//post/comments template
Comments: {{comments.length}}
```

Comment: This allows for an `{{if}}` but not `{{else}}`, as I require.

Comment: I'd say {{outlet in post}} = if ("post/1/comments") {{post/comments}} else {{post/index}}

Comment: But then I'm concerning the comments template with post output.  Seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

May be this looks good to you.

```
//post controller
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   isChildRouteActive: false,
});

//child route
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  parentController: Ember.computed( function() {
    return this.controllerFor('post');
  }),

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.get('parentController').set('isChildRouteActive', false);
  },

  deactivate: function() {
    this.get('parentController').set('isChildRouteActive', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks pretty good but is there any way to do this without knowing the explicit name of the parent controller?